# Ajax post data to php success but not post data over 12k length

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have php7 server on Windows2012 in IIS
When i post text data (name fgx in code) 12950 length and below  with ajax , it is success and data posted to php form.
When i try 12957+ length data post, its success from ajax but, no any data posted php form. 
When i check posted data length in php, it show me undefined .

**AJAX POST CODE**

```
        $.ajax({            
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            ipdata: fgx
            
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            
                    $('#info').empty();
                    $('#info').append(`
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" id="alarma">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                      <strong>Datalar post success.<br><br>` + msg + `</strong>
                    </div>`);
                    
        }               
    });
```

**PHP POST CODE**

```
    if( isset($_POST['ipdata'])){
    
    $incdata=$_POST['ipdata'];

    echo $incdata;

    }
```

**I tried;**
ajax post data type = text
ajax post cache = false
ajax proccessdata = false
i checked php post max size and upload max size is 128M

Comment: So you are saying that https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size is set to a larger number

Comment: You lost me at _"its success from ajax but, no any data posted php form."_. I have no idea what you mean here.

Comment: If you are checking the value of `ipdata` in PHP and it shows `undefined` that means your javascript isn't seeing the source of the content to send to PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson he means that no data is posted whatsoever when the length exceeds the limit - which is correct.

Comment: @peterxz - Not saying that you are wrong, but it's better if we let the OP actually clarify what they mean instead of us spending time guessing. That just leads to misunderstandings.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I mean thats fair, might just be me being bilingual myself or the fact that Ive encountered this issue fairly recently but I know exactly thats what he means :P Its not that broken if you think about what those individual words mean to someone who is not native. But anyways this is /off

Comment: @epascarello post max size already updated from 8M to 128M

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Mean is "ajax success code is return me success, but php post value is null"

Comment: @imvain2 when i add `alert(fgx.length)` in ajax function, i can see length 12957+, but data is not post php. php show me post data undefined, when data is below 12950 characters its successfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I resolved problem with upgrade php from 7.4.6 to 7.4.11**

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem recently in production. You want to increase your `post max size` variable in your php.ini - i had a similar issue where 128MB was not enough even though it was only ~30k characters.

You should also make sure that you increase the memory limit of the PHP script that you are posting to, as you are likely to be also hitting the ceiling there which could also be the problem. Depending on what you're doing in that script you might also want to set time limit to 0 (or a large number).

Comment: My post function working below 3 sec. Post maxsize already upgraded from 8M to 128M and memory limit upgraded from 32M to 256M. Im reading 2Kb text file and i process it. So, post max size should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

To narrow the search, I would inspect the traffic (either by sniffing it or checking with the browser's debug tools).

If the data *does* get sent, then I'd try checking the POST data server side some other way:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

or, if available,

```
$data = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

If you're running form-encoded data on a CGI, then that's a problem because neither access is available, I think (but CONTENT_LENGTH envvar should be present). You might be able to install PECL HTTP extension and thus have `http_get_request_body()` available, or use the OOP

```
$req  = new http\Env\Request();
$data = $req->getBody();
```

This should tell you where the data disappears. Making it reappear might be tricky though, unless you can change the server configuration.

Another thing I'd try is to send *two* variables, the first holding the second's length:

```
 {
      fgxc  : fgx.length,
      ipdata: fgx
 }
```

and then send a fixed string - a sequence of A's, say - in place of fgx. I had it happen to me that a very specific string sequence got edited out of a stream due to a misconfigured firewall that mistook it for a script injection attack.

If 12570 "A"'s pass, and 12570 bytes of fgx *don't*, then it's something to do with the content - and you might be able to work around it by sending it base64 encoded with `btoa()`, say. Then run `base64_decode` in the PHP code and you're set.

Comment: i can see posted data on debug window. [link]https://prnt.sc/uxhrmh .  But data is not posted, cause my ` if( isset($_POST['ipdata'])){ proces....}`  code is not trigger in php code. so , i get error from `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');` . I am not particularly use CGI features . I tried with length , result is same [link] https://prnt.sc/uxhx2u

Comment: I was encrypt with `btoa()` and i see post data in debug window , but i cant see post data on php. Its undefined again.  [link](https://prnt.sc/uxi52h)

Comment: Can you see anything in php://stdin or using one of the alternative functions? Also, what do you see in the server logs? It could be a slash-redirect. It happened to me with Laravel once.

Comment: `[14-Oct-2020 09:12:48 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Notice:  Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown on line 0
[14-Oct-2020 09:12:48 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory. in Unknown on line 0
[14-Oct-2020 09:12:48 Europe/Istanbul] PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST data can't be buffered; all data discarded in Unknown on line 0`  I found this logs in php7.4.6ErrorLog . I check my disk, its free.

Comment: Okay, Now you know. It is a permission problem. Have you tried googling that message? (I will probably do that later, I have limited bandwidth now)